# What's going wrong with my sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I try to open a connection to my sqlite database, when this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amirjodelmans/Desktop/chemcalc.py", line 3, in <module>
    hassan = sqlite3.connect("Untitled/Applications/molairemassa.db")
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The database can be found in the exact map, as shown in the error message, and this is the only code I've written:

```
import sqlite3

hassan = sqlite3.connect("Untitled/Users/amirjodelmans/Applications/molairemassa.db")
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Why do those paths differ? And what is `Untitled`? Don't macOS home directory paths usually start with `/Users`?

Comment: you pass a relative path to the connect function, what's strange is that in the traceback you use one path and in the example you show something different, in simpler words you pass wrong path to your database file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just put the wrong path in the string.

Could you try to change your path to an absolute path like this:

```
import sqlite3

hassan = sqlite3.connect("/Users/amirjodelmans/Applications/molairemassa.db")
```

Generally, if a path starts with `/`, it means an absolute path, if path starts with `./` or other alphanumerics, it represents an relative path.